# how to fetch live external data as its value to a cell of google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Say I have a simple table as:

```
name | value   |
GOOG | 539.27  |
AAPL | 118.3   |
```

I want the values `539.27` and `118.3` be lively updated from a source like here. The value is in some particular place of the DOM structure of the web page.

`https://www.google.com/finance?q=goog`

Is it even possible to fetch dynamically by the value in the first column?

`https://www.google.com/finance?q={value from the first column, can be "GOOG" / "AAPL"}`

Comment: @pnuts that is awesome! Thanks. Never thought they are so kind to provide such great tool. But what if they don't have this? Is it possible to load data from external pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request URLS from external sources using the [URLFetch API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/). After retrieving the response, you can parse it into an xml object using the [XML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) or handle the response as a JSON object by parsing the response using the [JSON service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#working_with_json)